# Get to response in Express in a promise?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I have some code with *Express*:

```
let promiseLink = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    app.post('/recipes', (req, res) => {
        resolve(req.body.linkText)
    })
})
promiseLink.then(function(value) {
    /* some code that I can't show, but is not much */
    .end(function (result) {
        let result = result.body
    }) 
})
```

Now, my question is, is there a way to get to the response of the post function from the `.end(function)..` block? Furthermore, if there is, I want to send raw html code, what would be the best way to do that? If there is not a way to get to the response, can I restructure my code so that I can?

Answer (score 1):

In your Promise, you can resolve() with any value you want. Just add the response, such as:

```
app.post('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    resolve({linkText: req.body.linkText, response: res})
})
```

The .then() `value` will be this object, or however you choose to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
let promiseLink = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    app.post('/recipes', (req, res) => {
      resolve({response: res, linkText: req.body.linkText})
    })
})
promiseLink.then(function({response, linkText}) {
    /* some code that I can't show, but is not much */
    .end(function(result) {
        // you can read response here now
        let result = result.body
    })
})
```

Comment: What is this `.end` inside `then` sorcery?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni It was in OP's code, which he says he can't divulge, but we can probably assume that it works.

Comment: I believe these comments are to question, not to an answer :)

Comment: @extempl Yeah :P Let's move it to the question.